# Linux | Python | `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` & `MemoryError`

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu# python2 ./example.py
######## filename: mp3/Brad-Sucks--Total-Breakdown.mp3
Failed fingerprinting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/__init__.py", line 79, in fingerprint_d   irectory
    song_name, hashes, file_hash = iterator.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
    raise value
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 17, in <module>
    song = djv.recognize(FileRecognizer, "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/mp3/Brad-Suc   ks--Total-Breakdown.mp3")
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/__init__.py", line 169, in recognize
    return r.recognize(*options, **kwoptions)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/recognize.py", line 41, in recognize
    return self.recognize_file(filename)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/recognize.py", line 29, in recognize_fi   le
    frames, self.Fs, file_hash = decoder.read(filename, self.dejavu.limit)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/decoder.py", line 51, in read
    audiofile = AudioSegment.from_file(filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 505   , in from_file
    p = subprocess.Popen(conversion_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subp   rocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Anybody can help me? I am a fresh man about python.

I wanna run a Python project which is proved to be correct in a Raspberry pi zero W, the system on it is a linux like Debian, I have already installed Python 2 and python 3.

when i killed the error above, another error arised like below:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu# python2 example.py                     ######## filename: mp3/Brad-Sucks--Total-Breakdown.mp3
Fingerprinting channel 1/2 for mp3/Brad-Sucks--Total-Breakdown.mp3
Failed fingerprinting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/__init__.py", line 79, in fingerprint_directory
    song_name, hashes, file_hash = iterator.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
    raise value
MemoryError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 17, in <module>
    song = djv.recognize(FileRecognizer, "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/mp3/Brad-Sucks--Total-Breakdown.mp3")
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/__init__.py", line 169, in recognize
    return r.recognize(*options, **kwoptions)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/recognize.py", line 41, in recognize
    return self.recognize_file(filename)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/recognize.py", line 32, in recognize_file
    match = self._recognize(*frames)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/recognize.py", line 17, in _recognize
    matches.extend(self.dejavu.find_matches(d, Fs=self.Fs))
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/__init__.py", line 118, in find_matches
    hashes = fingerprint.fingerprint(samples, Fs=Fs)
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/fingerprint.py", line 83, in fingerprint
    noverlap=int(wsize * wratio))[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 1315, in specgram
    mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 759, in _spectral_helper
    result = np.conjugate(result) * result
MemoryError
```

Anybody meet the similary problem before ?

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help you.

Comment: no code needed, it looks that there no "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/mp3/Brad-Suc   ks--Total-Breakdown.mp3" such file, i believe extra spaces is the reason

Comment: https://git.oschina.net/leochan007/dejavu, can you get the code on this website?

Comment: @k.biao No, we cannot. Please post relevant code excerpts here.

Comment: @ifconfig https://git.oschina.net/leochan007/dejavu, or https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu . these are the codes, I run them both, the same error occurs. can you try to run it? thanks

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I got the code from open source, you can download it on the Github, link is above, thank you so much.

Comment: If you aren't willing to put in an effort to ask a good question, you shouldn't expect people to put in effort to answer it. Voting to close.

Comment: lol, found the issue, looks that lib depends on pydub and failed on subprocess Popen call. Check pydub page https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub, how to setup dependencies - ffmpeg.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm willing to. not only because i am not clear what code to post, but the code is too long to post. so i tell you the link to download the whole project, thank you anyway.beg your pardon.

Comment: @Reishin thank you so much, when i trying to install ffmpeg, the terminal remind me 

    `E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate`

I am solving it

Comment: @Reishin You are a genius, the error is killed. though another problem arises.

    File "/home/pi/Downloads/dejavu/dejavu/__init__.py", line 79, in fingerprint_directory
  
    `song_name, hashes, file_hash = iterator.next()`
 
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, `in next
  
    raise value`
 
    MemoryError

Answer (score 0):

way to solve `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Install `FFmpeg` or `Libav`

Cause FFmpeg is almost quited by Linux, I installed Libva

`sudo apt-get install libav-tools`

way to solve `MemoryError`

Change a small mp3 file to fingerprint and recongnize

Cause the RAM of my CPU is too small to process the big file